# How to access drives other than C: in Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In the Windows Subsystem for Linux, I can access the `C:` drive as `/mnt/c`.

How can I access other drive letters, such as optical discs and network mounts? They do not show up under `/mnt` for me.

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How can I access other drive letters, such as optical discs and network mounts?

At the moment there are limitations on what drives are mounted:

> In order for a drive to show up under /mnt/ it must meet the following
>   criteria:
>
> 1. The drive must be a fixed drive
> 2. The drive must be formatted to NTFS.

This has been raised as an issue: [Drives other than C: are not mounted in /mnt #1079](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1079). It is still marked as "Open".

Answer (score 7):

Update to [DavidPostill's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1129947/1277371):

Issue [Drives other than C: are not mounted in /mnt #1079](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1079) and related issue [Update /mnt #2237](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2237) now marked as closed, solutions below.

#### WSL2 Recommended method

> You will need to be on Windows 11 Build 22000 or higher to access this feature

Microsoft WSL2 docs [Get started mounting a Linux disk in WSL 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk) describes how this can be done in PowerShell terminal (PS) and WSL bash linux terminal ($).

1. Get DiskPath (DeviceID) of volume. `PS wmic diskdrive list brief`
2. Make disk available to wsl. `PS wsl --mount <DiskPath> --bare`
3. Should now be listed in wsl. (device path as /dev/*, where * is device name). (partitions indexed by number) `$ lsblk`
4. Identify filesystem of volume/partition under TYPE. `$ sudo blkid <DevicePath>`
5. Mount in powershell.

- Mount specific partition: `PS wsl --mount <DiskPath> --partition <PartitionNumber> --type <Filesystem>`
- Mount entire disk: `PS wsl --mount <DiskPath> --type <Filesystem>`

#### Using DrvFS

Microsoft blog post [File System Improvements to the Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/wsl/file-system-improvements-to-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux) describes how this can be done in the WSL bash terminal to mount using DrvFS.

e.g. for drive D

Mount: `$ sudo mkdir /mnt/d$ sudo mount -t drvfs D: /mnt/d`

Unmount: `$ sudo umount /mnt/d`

Comment: Missing like break. Need "$ sudo mkdir /mnt/d" and on 2nd line "$ sudo mount -t drvfs D: /mnt/"