# How to separate the container folder and images folder in Docker WSL2?

Tags: windows-10, docker, wsl2, docker-for-windows

Ok, there is a post [about changing the location](https://blog.codetitans.pl/post/howto-docker-over-wsl2-location/) of the Docker data,  but what if I need to place the containers' filesystem on one drive (SSD) but keep images on another (HDD)?

Is there a way to do this in WSL2?

Answer (score 0):

In the purest form of your question, I think I'd go with, "No."  As mentioned in the documentation:

> **Warning**: Do not directly manipulate any files or directories within `/var/lib/docker/`. These files and directories are managed by Docker.

And while Docker Desktop with WSL2 doesn't place the files in this directory, the concept would still hold true.

*However*, I think the way your question is phrased might be a bit ambiguous.  It all depends on what you mean by "container filesystem".  We could look at that two ways:

- The [`overlay2` filesystem](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/) that Docker uses (at least by default <sup>*1*</sup>) to provide the container layer stores the layers in the same location as those for the images.  As far as I can tell from the [Storage Driver documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/), there is no way to choose a different driver for containers vs. images.

  *<sub><sup>1</sup> Docker Desktop currently provides a Beta option to use Containerd for pulling images.  On my system, with this in place, the storage driver is `stargz`.</sub>*
- But you can also mount storage as Docker Volumes into your containers, of course.  By doing this, you can specify a location for that Volume that is on the WSL2 distribution's filesystem that you are using.

Since you've already moved your `docker-desktop-data` to another drive, I assume that means that your distribution is already on the "original" drive.  Regardless, see [my answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1731302/1210833) for updated instructions on how to move distributions.  The Blog you referenced is a bit out of date -- It will work, but there are easier ways at this point.